# Where do you edit default include libraries in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I worked on a project that included a number of libraries, but it seems I accidentally set these libraries to be included in all future projects made with VS2013. This is causing a number of linker errors whenever I use "inherit from parent or project defaults" for included libraries in a project property page. Where can I edit these defaults and remove them from the list of automatic includes?

Comment: Sounds like you added a property page, or edited a default one. Look in the property manager: View->Other Windows->Property Manager.

Comment: Ah, it appears that I accidentally edited the global property page instead of creating a local one. Thank you for cluing me into where to look, Cameron.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that VS2013 includes a global project property sheet with all projects. You can find this sheet by selecting View -> Property Manager from the menu line. The global sheet is named "Microsoft.cpp..user" and is included by default in both Debug and Release configurations. Any edits made to this file will propagate to all VC++ projects that you will make or have made. Edit responsibly.